# Access to a EWS Exchange Services

Tags: exchange, web-services

I'm trying to get `EWS` services work from a new `2013 Exchange Server`.
If I put services url: https://192.168.1.XXX/ews/services.wsdl in my browser I get an `xml` (the wsdl) with all my services. Perfect.

Then I open my `Exchange Console` and give permission to al my organization to use `EWS`:

```
Set-OrganizationConfig –EwsApplicationAccessPolicy:EnforceBlockList //--> to allow all clients to use EWS
Set-OrganizationConfig -EwsEnabled:$true //--> to allow all my organization to user EWS
```

So, then I open my `SoapUI Soap client` and I put the services url. Perfect.

The system then ask me for a user, I give my administrator user, the same as I use to get into `ECP` page of Exchange administration (so the user is correct)

The issue is that I always get:

> Error loading [https://192.168.1.XXX/ews/Services.wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null

I think could be a permission issue, but if I run  Test-WebservicesConnectivity everything seems ok.

```
[PS] C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Scripts>Test-WebServicesConnectivity

Source                              ServiceEndpoint                     Scenario                       Result  Latency
                                                                                                                  (MS)
------                              ---------------                     --------                       ------  -------
WIN-AG0N98H6L29_XXX_yyy       win-ag0n98h6l29_XXX_yyy       Detección automática: prove... Success      36
WIN-AG0N98H6L29_XXX_YYY       win-ag0n98h6l29_XXX_yyy       EWS: GetFolder                 Success     222
```

Does someone know if I have to grant some special permission in role group to get authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it has to do with NTLM Authentication.

See here [EWS Authentication.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for you Time. After one thousand tries I found in the ECP page, in servers section, in "virtual directory", the configuration of EWS. There you can set NTLM and/or basic authetication. When I set basic auth, I manage to get services from Exchange, in my SoapUi client. It seems that the problem was between my keyboard and my chair  :^)

Comment: No Problem. Nice to hear that it works now.